# In django How to display parent model data with child model data in change list view?

Tags: python, django

Example: I have an Invoice as the parent model and invoice details as the child model. I would like to display the child details in the Invoice model admin as entries of the invoice.  Target is to achieve a consolidated view in the listing page itself. Is there any alternative to achieve this: It should look like this:

```
Invoice 1:
 -details 1
 -details 2
Invoice 2:
 -details 1
 -details 2
 -details 3
```

Is there some template available as this in django 1.6.5?

Answer (score 5):

Assume the following example:

*models.py*

```
class Invoice(models.model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()  # for example

class InvoiceDetail(models.model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice)
```

*views.py*

```
# example, don't fetch all in production
return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', {'invoices': Invoice.objects.all()})
```

Then your template would be as:

*mytemplate.html*

```
{% for invoice in invoices %}
    <p>Invoice {{ invoice.id }} ({{ invoice.date }})
    {% if invoice.invoicedetail_set %}
        <ul>
        {% for detail in invoice.invoicedetail_set %}
            <li>Detail {{ detail.id }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

For the admin interface, there is a very good tutorial in [Django documentation: Tutorial: Adding related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial02/#adding-related-objects).

Comment: This is when we write custom templates; I wish to override the admin template of invoice header with admin template of detail for changelist_ view. Is this possible, I tried using the template attribute of Invoice Admin to use the template of detail, but it doesn't render it.

Comment: My friend, you need to say those details in your question before someone spends time helping... The admin interface is a different matter. Slightly modified the answer.

Comment: You're awesome man. It really helped I was looking out the parent, child view. Thank you so much

Comment: do you guys know how to add a form  to add new detail in the current invoice. if invoices for separated in pages?