# How to display parent model with its child model in a template

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here is my structure:

**model.py**

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    room_no = models.IntegerField()
    floor_no = models.IntegerField()
    contact_no = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'doctor'

class DoctorSpecialization(models.Model):
    doc = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, models.DO_NOTHING)
    spec = models.ForeignKey('Specialization', models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'doctor_specialization'

class Specialization(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=45)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'specialization'
```

I would like to display this on my template just like on this post:
[In django How to display parent model data with child model data in change list view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30435949/in-django-how-to-display-parent-model-data-with-child-model-data-in-change-list)

```
Internal Medicine
 - Joanne Doe M.D.
 - Andrew Fuller M.D.
 - Nancy Davolio M.D.
OB-Gyne
 - John Doe M.D.
 - Janet Leverling M.D.
ENT
 - Margaret Peacock M.D.
 - Steven Buchanan M.D.
 - Laura Callahan M.D.
 - Michael Suyama M.D.
```

**But the problem is i have many to many relationship structure. I am new to django please your help is highly appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to render your structure with

```
doctors = {}
for spec in Specialization.objects.all():
    doctors[spec.title] = [doc_spec.doc.name for doc_spec in DoctorSpecialization.objects.filter(spec=spec)]
```

then pass this dict to template:

```
from django.template import Context, loader

template = loader.get_template('<path_to_your_template>')
context = Context({"doctors": doctors})
template.render(context)
```

or you can use [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut for this part:

```
render(request, '<path_to_your_template>', {"doctors": doctors})
```

and render it using double `for` loop:

```
{% for title, doc_list in doctors.items %}
    <strong>{{ title }}:</strong><br>
    <ul>
    {% for doc in doc_list %}
      <li>{{ doc }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: please wait as i try

Comment: Let me know if you success. I can add other parts of the code if you have problems.

Comment: sure thing sir.

Comment: sir i have trouble working on the template how can i access the doctor name by `forloop`?

Comment: Got this error sir `ValueError: Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 1.`

Comment: Where you've got this error? I cannot help you without exact location.

Comment: on the for loop inside the template sir

Comment: First or second for?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Try adding `.items` to the `doctor` in the first for loop in the template.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123136/discussion-between-shift-n-tab-and-domen-blenkus).